# What is the difference between a URI and URL?

Tags: http, url, uri

What is a URI, and what is the difference between URL and URI?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, a URI identifies a resource, and a URL shows you how to find it. Thus URI deals with parsing, local/absolute paths, etc. and URL deals with connecting to streams and such.