# Does a URI include the protocol?

Tags: http, url, protocols, uri

Will the URI of this URL, for example
http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport
include http:// at the front, making the URI http://news.bbc.co.uk ?

Or, is the URI just news.bbc.co.uk ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a URI and URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428196/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-url)

Answer (score 11):

A [URI per RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) has the grammar:

> ```
> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

So, yes, the scheme `http` as well as the separating `:` and the `//` prefix of the *hier-part* are part of the URI. `news.bbc.co.uk` is only the [*host*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2).

Comment: Cheers. that really helped a lot? If the www prefix was also included, would that also be part of the URI, or would that only be part of the URL? Thanks again

Comment: @Rob, yes, `www` is part of the host name (see the link at the end of this answer).  You can't assume `www.bbc.co.uk` and `bb.co.uk` are equivalent host names in either a URI or a URL.  They may be or many not.

Comment: @Rob: [A URL is also a URI](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.3): “The term "Uniform Resource Locator" (URL) refers to the subset of URIs that, in addition to identifying a resource, provide a means of locating the resource by describing its primary access mechanism (e.g., its network "location").”

Answer (score 2):

The [URI Scheme](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html) (http, ftp, file et.c.) is part of the uri.